# how to run concurrant db connections in codeigniter normal mysql and custom pdo

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

Afternoon all.
I have a strange question.
I need to have two connections to our db in codeigniter instance.
I need to have the standard ci method but i also need to create a pdo class instance for use in new feature setup.
We are unfortunately in the position where we have to run a v1.0 system using the old db connectivity and a new v2.0 system using a pdo db object.

**How can I go about creating a global instance of this pdo class so that it only gets instantiated once per process call to codeigniter**.

Answer (score 0):

you should add another DB in `application/config/database.php` and change `dbdriver` and `hostname` like

```
$db['pdodb']['hostname'] = "mysql:host=localhost'";
$db['pdodb']['username'] = "root";
$db['pdodb']['password'] = "";
$db['pdodb']['database'] = "your_db";
$db['pdodb']['dbdriver'] = "pdo";
$db['pdodb']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['pdodb']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['pdodb']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['pdodb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['pdodb']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['pdodb']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['pdodb']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['pdodb']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['pdodb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['pdodb']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and you can load database like this

```
$pdodb= $this->load->database('pdodb', TRUE);
```

and finally you can execute query like this

```
$query = $pdodb->select('col1, col2,col3')->get('your_table');
```

for more information about [multiple database](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html)

Comment: ok but can i call this once in the start of the process and have it available wherever I need to use it?

Comment: when you want to execute query then first you need to database object `$pdodb= $this->load->database('pdodb', TRUE);` this line return you DB object and follow execute query process (above i mention 2 lines of code that help to execute query)